# "Pasted from" URL info --> How to transfer this var to Javascript and / or AHK?

Tags: javascript, autohotkey

Please, answer any-of the three-parts:

When I copy (simple text) from the Web into MS Office One-Note the program detects the url where I'm copying from: i.e.

> *The following example is a working script. Whenever it is running, it
>   will briefly display...*
>
> Pasted from http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Clipboard.htm

1) On my local machine:
Do you know the code to capture this "Pasted from" variable in AHK?

FYI: %clipboard% prints (returns) the text, but not the "Pasted from" info.

2a) How about basic **Javascript** to deal with the current clipboard contents?

What is the equivalent of the basic (ahk) %clipboard% var in Javascript? (i.e. Text only / Not the extra info)

2b) Can Javascript detect where Web content-currently in the clipboard-was (copy/) pasted from?

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure this is Meta-information added by the browser (Internet Explorer?), and detected by OneNote by some special format that the browser offers the clipboard cutting in.

Not sure this can be replicated in JavaScript, nor AutoHotkey.

**Edit**: I did some research, but couldn't find any hard information on how they do this. The only thing I found is a general overview on [copying and pasting HTML](https://web.archive.org/web/20140526183255/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pbaer/archive/2004/05/03/125443.aspx) from one of the OneNote developers.

If this is available from Chrome and Firefox as well, it might be worth investigating whether AutoHotkey can access the clipboard on a more detailed level, to fetch the right format with the annotation in it. The data *must* be somewhere in the clipboard in that case.

Comment: Thanks, FYI: This works "coming from" Chrome and Firefox, so (I think) the info should be available (at least) to AutoHotkey.

Comment: @This interesting. I added a paragraph to my answer.

Comment: I will ask @AHK forum in the future (need to to sign-up), thanks for helping get me started.